# Update UI after separate thread has detected a change in object state

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency

I am currently working through what seems to be a classic multithreading problem(I am still learning multithreading).  In my application I send a request to a website on a button click, then have a class that repeatedly requests the website to see if there has been a change every 10 seconds. Once a change is noticed, the UI should update. I want to make sure this process is done on a separate thread so that it does not interfere with the UI.  I have tried using ScheduledExecutorService however I'm stuck at the part where the Runnable thread realizes a change has occurred and is unable to return a value to let the main process know to update the UI. How would I go about this problem? Thanks in advance.

### UI_FragmentClass.java

```
sendPollCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(!currentModuleInfo.getEngStatus().equals("POLL")){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
                AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("Confirm Send Poll Command? This may take a few minutes.").setPositiveButton("Confirm", new 
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {



                    mPresenter.commandSequence("POLL", currentModuleInfo.getItemid(), "");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Poll Command sent...Waiting for response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPresenter.checkForUpdate(currentModuleInfo.getItemid(), currentModuleInfo.getEngStatus(), currentModuleInfo.getTime());
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

    }
});
```

### presenterClass.java

```
public void checkForUpdate(String id, String engStatus, String lstMsgTime) {


class Check implements Runnable {
    String iden, eng, time;

    Check( String id, String engStatus, String lstMsgTime) {
        iden = id;
        eng = engStatus;
        time = lstMsgTime;
    }

    public void run() {

        Module check = getIndividualModule(iden);

        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("LOCAL");
        System.out.println("engine status: " + eng);
        System.out.println("time: " + time);

        System.out.println("\n" + "CURRENT");
        System.out.println("engine status: " + check.getEngStatus());
        System.out.println("time: " + check.getTime());
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");



        if (!check.getEngStatus().equals(eng) || !check.getTime().equals(time)){
            System.out.println("CHANGE DETECTED");





            System.out.println("update panel");
            return;
        }
    }
}

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Check(id, engStatus, lstMsgTime), 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to achieve this.

1. Create a background service that will check the updates of the website
2. If update found send broadcast receiver to notify the UI to populate update.

It seems your are new in Android too. Here are some example [Background Service](https://javatutorial.net/android-service-example), [Receiver to Update UI](http://lalit3686.blogspot.my/2012/06/how-to-update-activity-from-service.html) it's not recommended to perform network request every after X secs interval. Try to implement another wayout.